# Trying to use sortBy to sort a list of tuples

Tags: scala, implicits

In my scala eclipse worksheet I do:

```
val values: List[(Char, Int)] = List(('z', 7), ('b', 6))
                                                  //> values  : List[(Char, Int)] = List((z,7), (b,6))
val sortedValues = values.sortBy(_._1)          //> sortedValues  : <error> = List((b,6), (z,7))
```

I cannot understand why the sortBy function gives an `<error>` or how do find more information about it.

When I put the same code into a scala class, I get:

```
diverging implicit expansion for type scala.math.Ordering[B] starting with method Tuple9 in object Ordering
```

I see other threads with this error. But they are different cases.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Do you have any weird import that could conflict with Ordering of your tuples or the tuple's contents? If you try it on the REPL, do you get the same error? For me it works fine on the REPL, scala 2.10.1. Maybe it's a worksheet issue?

Comment: Looks like the implicit ordering is not properly resolved, sortBy is defined as follow : def sortBy[B](f: (A) ⇒ B)(implicit ord: math.Ordering[B]): List[A] Have you tried using a longer version of your sorting function ? Like values.sortBy(i => i._1) ?

Comment: What version of scala are you running? If you add that code directly to the REPL, do you get the same error?